# The onclick event of the span element nested in a button is not triggered on MS Edge when touched

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on a React component where a `span` element is nested in a `button` element, when the button is clicked, the `onclick` event of the `span` element should be triggered instead of the `onclick` event of the `button` element.

Below is my example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Event Propagation</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="alert('button onclick')">
 <span onclick="alert('span onclick');event.stopPropagation();">
     Click Me!
    </span>
</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Of course, the above is just a simple HTML and JavaScript, as my React component is quite complicated. Regardless, the above example produces the same effect. When I run the codes above on Chrome on Surface by touching the button, it works as expected, where *span onclick* is prompted.

[image: nested span click on Chrome]

However, when I run this on Microsoft Edge on Surface and touch on the button, the `onclick` of `button` is triggered and not the `span` event. May I know what is the logic behind and how could I resolve the issue?

[image: nested span click on Edge]

This has to be run on Edge because the actual React component will run on the WebView embedded in the UWP app.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you click the middle of the button. If you click the edges outside of your `<span>` (the padding), you click the button! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - Prevent Event Trigger on Parent From Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568550/react-prevent-event-trigger-on-parent-from-child)

Comment: @RoboRobok , clicking the button is with the mouse achieves the expected result on both Chrome and Edge. However, when touching the button with a finger on a touch screen works fine on Chrome, but Edge only triggers the event on the button. :(

Comment: Are you sure you point your finger on the span? Try zooming in and make sure you touch the text.

Comment: @keikai, not really. The problem is not the propagation, but the event of the nested child is never triggered when I touch the button on Edge on a touchscreen (I tested it on Surface).

Comment: @RoboRobok, I have updated the question with screen capture. When running the code on Chrome, the result is achieved without much effort. However, on Edge, it occasionally will work (under unknown circumstances).

Comment: You should not have an onclick inside a button, which in itself already has some onclick functionality out of the box. You should really think about creating semantic HTML that makes sense for a user instead of worrying on how to fix this.

Comment: Looks like you are making this test with the MS Edge (EdgeHTML) legacy browser. As your goal is to make it work with a web view, I suggest you try to make a test with the MS Edge Chromium web view2. It can help you to fix this issue. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2

Comment: @cloned, good point, I guess I have to figure this out. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, it is one of our plans to change to Chromium-based WebView 2. However, this would take time and we need to continue with the legacy WebView for now. :(

Comment: In that situation, I suggest you modify the web page design so that it can work with the MS Edge browser in touch mode.