# React - How to prevent an onMouseDown event listener stopping an onClick JSX function from executing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, dom-events, ref

I am currently stuck on a problem where the onClick function for a button of a child react component is not being triggered due to a mousedown event listener that has been defined in the parent component. The mousedown event listener closes a dropdown menu defined in the parent component. This appears to be interfering with a button of a child component as when I remove the mouse down event listener, the button's onclick appears to work again. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
// Parent Component
this.moreContainerRef = React.createRef();

handleClickOutside(event) {
    const clickedOutsideDropdown =
      this.moreContainerRef.current &&
      !this.moreContainerRef.current.contains(event.target);
    if (!clickedOutsideDropdown) return;
    this.setState({ moreMenuOpen: false });
}
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}

// In the render function
{moreMenuOpen && (
  <div className="more-dropdown">
    <ul>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn more-dropdown-button btn-light">
          Button
      </button>
    </ul>
  </div>
)}

// Child Component
<button onClick={() => functionNotBeingCalled()}>
  Child Button
</button>
```

Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So when you click on the child component, the drop down menu disappears is it?
Try using `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.preventDefault()` from the child component button click. [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: @H.Udara Hi, thanks for responding so quickly. Exactly, when a click the child component, (along with any other DOM element) the dropdown menu closes. The only problem is that when clicking on the button the JSX onClick callback doesn't execute. I have tried your suggestion of adding event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); but unfortunately the callback doesn't get called. I have check by adding breakpoints and a debugger; statement which makes me confident the onClick function is simply being ignored. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try a `console.log('im here')` inside the `functionNotBeingCalled()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - Prevent Event Trigger on Parent From Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568550/react-prevent-event-trigger-on-parent-from-child)

Comment: The 'im here' console log does not appear. I am also afraid that the thread that you have linked does not solve the problem either. I tried putting stopPropagation in the mousedown event listener as well but to no avail.  I have now tried to move the mousedown event listener into the child component to see if it would help. It did not, which leads me to think that the mousedown event listener seems to be preventing any onClick JSX logic from being executed. Have you got any other suggestions?

Comment: I think the "click" event and "mouse down" events are conflicting here. Try replacing the "mousedown" even with a "click" event. Also try the `stopPropagation` combined with this method.

Comment: That makes sense to me. The only problem is that I am using mousedown because I want the dropdown menu to close when the user clicks away from the component. Do you know how I can use an onclick function to detect a click away from the element?

Comment: Its the same, the `event.target` contains the element that was clicked. You just change the `mousedown` to `click` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Mousedown event is triggered before the onClick event so it will trigger first hence your menu will be closed and the onClick event won't be fired. As a workaround you can wrap you setState to close the menu on a `setTimeout` function to not close the menu immediately and actually fire the onClick event. Not the cleanest solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the `click` event listener rather than `mousedown`.

So change this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}
```

To this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside);
}
```