# Link card area that contains a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The grey area should be an `<a>` tag link. The black area is a `<button>` within the grey area. The button should have a `onClick` action.

When I click anything grey I want to access the `<a>` tag link. When I click the black area I want to trigger the button action. What is the proper and accessible way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: In the button's onclick handler, call `.stopPropagation()` on the click event. Or add an onclick handler to the link itself and call `.preventDefault()` to cancel based on `.currentTarget`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - Prevent Event Trigger on Parent From Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568550/react-prevent-event-trigger-on-parent-from-child)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
<style>
    .wrapper{
      position: relative;
    }
    
    a{
      display: block;
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: lightgray;
      border-radius: 1rem;
    }
    
    button{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: .5rem;
      left: .5rem;
      padding: .5rem;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: .5rem;
      color: white;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
   <a href="https://codepen.io/" target="_blank"></a>
   <button type="button" onclick="alert('Fired!')">Button</button>
</div>
```

See https://codepen.io/nubetonante/pen/PoQaOwO

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with Javascript by the way @ChrisG said, with `.stopPropagation()` or `.preventDefault()`.

Or if you want to do it with css only, then you could add a card-container, inside an a tag and a button like this:

```html
<div class="container">
   <a href="#"></a>
   <button></button>
</div>
```

Then make the container `position: relative;` and the button `position:absolute;` to position it above the `<a>` tag.
U also will need `z-index` to place it above.